# elasticsearch failed to find nested object under path

Tags: java, elasticsearch

Hello i have this ood error where in elasticsearch searching for data i get this error.

`

```
[2017-11-09 18:14:30,977][DEBUG][action.search            ] [Xorn] All shards failed for phase: [query]
RemoteTransportException[[Xorn][127.0.0.1:9300][indices:data/read/search[phase/query]]]; nested: SearchParseException[failed to parse search source [{"from":0,"size":15,"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"query_string":{"query":"ctDossierType:(TrademarkApplication)"}},{"nested":{"query":{"bool":{"must":{"query_string":{"query":"ntComments.comment:(xcbxcv)"}}}},"path":"ntComments"}},{"nested":{"query":{"bool":{"must":{"query_string":{"query":"ntComments.comment:(xcbxcv)"}}}},"path":"ntComments"}},{"nested":{"query":{"bool":{"must":{"query_string":{"query":"ntComments.comment:(xcbxcv)"}}}},"path":"ntComments"}},{"query_string":{"query":"design:(false)"}}]}},"sort":[{"stComparableApplicationNumber":{"order":"desc","missing":"_last","ignore_unmapped":true}}]}]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[nested] failed to find nested object under path [ntComments]];
Caused by: SearchParseException[failed to parse search source [{"from":0,"size":15,"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"query_string":{"query":"ctDossierType:(TrademarkApplication)"}},{"nested":{"query":{"bool":{"must":{"query_string":{"query":"ntComments.comment:(xcbxcv)"}}}},"path":"ntComments"}},{"nested":{"query":{"bool":{"must":{"query_string":{"query":"ntComments.comment:(xcbxcv)"}}}},"path":"ntComments"}},{"nested":{"query":{"bool":{"must":{"query_string":{"query":"ntComments.comment:(xcbxcv)"}}}},"path":"ntComments"}},{"query_string":{"query":"design:(false)"}}]}},"sort":[{"stComparableApplicationNumber":{"order":"desc","missing":"_last","ignore_unmapped":true}}]}]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[nested] failed to find nested object under path [ntComments]];
```

`

the funny thing is it works when no argument is inputed in search field. System is duplicate to other system, and on other one it works. The thing is its all auto generated.

nested query
`

```
{
  "nested" : {
    "query" : {
      "bool" : {
        "must" : {
          "query_string" : {
            "query" : "ntComments.comment:(blablabla)"
          }
        }
      }
    }
    "path" : "ntComments"
  }
} `

nested bool query


`{
   "bool" : {
    "must" : {
     "query_string" : {
      "query" : "ntComments.comment:(blablabla)"
     }
    }
   }
  }
 ntComments
 must : {
  "bool" : {
   "must" : [ {
    "query_string" : {
     "query" : "ctDossiertype:(typetypetype)"
    }
   }, { 
    "nested" : {
     "query" : {
      "bool" : {
       "must" : {
        "query_string" : {
         "query" : "ntComments.comment:(blablabla)"
        }
       }
      }
     },
     "path" : "ntComments"
    }
   }, {
    "nested" : {
     "query" : {
      "bool" : {
       "must" : {
        "query_string" : {
         "query" : "ntComments.comment:(blablabla)"
        }
       }
      }
     }, 
     "path" : "ntComments"
    }
   }]
  }
 }
```

`

im going crazy over it, any ideas why its not working would be great.

Comment: Make sure the mappings on both systems are equal!

Comment: I don't know if it is related to your problem, but in line 7 there is an 'm' missing in `"query" : "ntComments.coment:(blablabla)"`

Comment: it was typing error in stackoverflow. Mapping is equal, because changed are only labels.